# Error in search view activity

Tags: android

I try to make search view in my app. i'm use this source code, but it showing error.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.cari, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =

            //error here   (SearchView) = menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
```

anyone know why this source error?

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: post the logcat or tell in which line exactly are you facing the error and what error it is ?

Comment: i can't sir, because its error. But the error says "SearchView cannot be resolved to a variable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to import your `searchview` first.

example :

```
 import android.widget.searchview
```